# Linking two databases with code first framework

Tags: mysql, asp.net-mvc, database, table-relationships

Using code first framework in mvc, I have created a database of artists, but I want to now create a database of artwork for these individual artists. Something like this:
Artist Id=1 -> Artwork Id=1,2,3,4 , Artist Id=2 -> Artwork Id=1,2,3,4 etc
How would I go about doing this using code first entity framework?

Comment: In one database you are creating multiple *tables*

Comment: @Drew I'm new to mvc so I'm not exactly sure how you do this, can i create a table within the same model? And then how would I go about linking the tables together? Thanks, Will